# Is there a way to time things in Python?

Tags: python, time

Is there a way to time the amount of time that happened between (for example) button a being pressed and button b being pressed in Python? If so, how?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dislike to search before ask, isnt't it?
there is a module surprisingly called `time`

```
import time
start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    print i
stop = time.time()
print 'elapsed time in seconds', stop - start
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the time function

```
import time

start = time.time()
#do stuff
end = time.time()
logger.debug("time:{0}".format(end-start))
```